# JS как правильно в промисе использовать функции

Tags: javascript, promise

затертый до дыр вопрос выполнить одну функцию после другой. Очевидный путь - промис, однако вызов функции такого вида func(arg)() не работает.

```js
let myPromise = new Promise
(
 (resolve, reject) => 
 {
  firstFunction(param)();
    resolve();
 }
);
myPromise.then(secondFunction(param)());
```

Но, secondFunction не ждёт выполнение первой.

Если поставить таймаут, то всё ОК:

```js
firstFunction(param)();
setTimeout(secondFunction(param)(), 2000);
```

обе функции возвращают анонимную:

```js
function firstFunction(param)
{
 return () =>
 {
             ...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myPromise.then(secondFunction(param));
```

```js
let myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let a = firstFunction(3000000000)();
  console.log(a);
  resolve();
});
myPromise.then(secondFunction(25));

function firstFunction(param) {
  return () => {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < param; i++) {}
    return i;
  }
}

function secondFunction(param) {
  return () => {
    console.log(param);
  }
}
```

Comment: Пробовал, так тоже не ждёт

Comment: @Bigata Тогда давайте [mcve].

Comment: @Yaant, хм похоже работает, видимо у меня в приложении баг. Вот пример, рабочий вроде let myPromise = new Promise
(
 (resolve, reject) => 
 {
  let a = firstFunction(3000000000)();
  console.log(a);
    resolve();
 }
);
myPromise.then(secondFunction(25));

function firstFunction(param)
{
 return () =>
 {
  let i;
  for(i = 0; i < param; i++)
  {
  }
  return i;
 }
}
function secondFunction(param)
{
 return () =>
 {
  console.log(param);
 }
}

Comment: @Bigata Возможно, Вы запускаете необновленный код.

Comment: @Igor нет-нет, обновляю конечно.

Comment: @Bigata Хорошо. В ответе сообщения в консоли в нужном порядке?

Comment: @Igor, да в том которое нужно.

Comment: @Bigata Очень хорошо. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.